# Docker, adding host ip address to new container

Tags: docker

I have a docker image that I'm going to use in order to create new container. I have an PostgreSQL database that runs on my machine that I want to connect to my future container.

I know that new created container will be located in `172.17.0.0/16` network, so I have added this network for my `listen_addresses` parameter in PostgreSQL configuration.

Now in order to create container I need to write something like this:

```
docker run --add-host=connection_name:connection_ip container_name
```

In `connection_ip` what I kind of address I should write? Should I write `localhost` or I need to write static IP address where I can have an access from outside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't rely on IP addresses of locally-generated networks (172.17.0.0/16 for instance), if you want your container to work everywhere: some high-level Docker engine management systems, like Kubernetes, make changes to those default networks, and some cloud Docker hosting environments also do the same.

Docker handles specifically your need for container to host communications with the option `--network`. When running a new Docker container, it lets you specify a network name to link with, without the need to give any IP address.

You need a rather **recent** Docker engine (at least version 1.9), for this option to be available.

**Here is how to solve your problem with this new option:**

We suppose that your host is named **myhost** (output of the `hostname` command).

You have to launch your container this way:

```
docker run --network host container_name
```

The value of the `--network` parameter, `host`, means you want to connect this container to your host.

Now, from inside your container, the host is named **myhost**. Moreover, an IP address has been mapped to the hostname **myhost** in the container's `/etc/hosts`, and **this IP address is allocated in the network 127.0.0.0/8**.

Therefore, postgresql connections from the container to **myhost**:5432 will be seen coming from 127.0.0.0/8, from the host point of view. **Then, you just need to add 127.0.0.0/8 to your `listen_addresses` postgresql parameter.**

Comment: So what should I write into `connection_ip` ?

Comment: Nothing: do not use `--add-host`. Use the command I have written: `docker run --network host container_name`

Comment: So inside my continer where I must write connection to PostgreSQL I just write `localhost:5432` ?

Comment: No, as written above you need to write myhost:5432 (myhost is the output of the command hostname on the host, thus this is the host name of the host)

Answer (score 0):

You should use 0.0.0.0 for `listen_addresses` in your PostgreSQL configuration to listen on *both* interfaces.

If you really want to run on an specific IP address, you must create a network with `docker network create` and use the `--ip` option to docker-run or docker-create.

Answer (score 0):

To connect to your Postgres Database from the container, you can retrieve the default gateway IP address from your [entrypoint](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) script.

From the container you can retrieve the docker host IP with `ip route show`

```
# ip route show
default via 172.17.0.1 dev eth0 
172.17.0.0/16 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.0.2
```

Then the default route is your host IP (here 172.17.0.1)

At this point, pay attention to the host's firewall which can block the connection

In your entrypoint script you can retrieve the host IP with ip route show | awk '/default/ {print $3}'. Then you can pass this IP through an environment variable and retrieve it in your application.